# Hints, not walkthrough, for Braid?

Tags: braid

I love the game but a little stuck, and not willing to look at walkthrough sites.

Anyone know of places to find "hints" to help through levels without giving away the solution completely?

Comment: A suggestion, if I may: you could also describe your particular problem and someone here might be able to give you a hint directly.

Comment: Have to agree with @Aubergine here. Why not make us a place to find hints about getting through some of the levels?

Comment: Agreed with @Aubergine... that's essentially the whole point of this site.

Comment: A good design point of Braid is that one doesn't have to complete a level (or world) in entirety before attempting the next. You can make progress elsewhere, then return with a fresh mind. This is much less frustrating than being literally stuck as happens in linear puzzle games like Portal.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This blog has pretty good hints for each world, without explicitly giving away the solutions. Unfortunately it is down now, but here are the individual links from web.archive.org:

- World 1 : Not covered by the blog
- [World 2](http://web.archive.org/web/20120929075050/http://lungfishopolis.com/2009/04/braid-hints-world-2-no-spoilers/)
- [World 3](http://web.archive.org/web/20120929073453/http://lungfishopolis.com/2009/04/braid-hints-world-3-no-spoiler/)
- [World 4](http://web.archive.org/web/20120929075050/http://lungfishopolis.com/2009/04/braid-hints-world-4-no-spoiler/)
- [World 5](http://web.archive.org/web/20120929073614/http://lungfishopolis.com/2009/05/braid-hints-world-5-no-spoiler/)
- [World 6](http://web.archive.org/web/20120929073619/http://lungfishopolis.com/2009/05/braid-hints-world-6-no-spoilers/)

Comment: Thanks..this is the best answer, but i agree I'll ask for specific as well so it gets captured here

Comment: +1 - Wish I'd seen that before spoiling "The Cloud Bridge" :-(

Comment: As per [this suggested edit](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/37434), most of the links are now down.

Comment: @galacticninja they are fixed already (mostly by Anna lear )

Answer (score 3):

The names of the levels are sometimes subtle hints, eg. leap of faith, phase, just out of reach.