# How do I get out of the pit?

Tags: braid

In Braid 3-1, there's a locked door on the opposite side of a large pit. At the bottom of the pit there's a goomba carrying the key to the door. I've managed to time it so that when I jump down onto the goomba, I pick up the key and bounce back up - but I'm not bouncing up high enough to escape the pit. What's the trick?

Comment: note: for further hints without too many spoilers, [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2679/hints-not-walkthrough-for-braid) is the perfect resource, the answer linking to http://lungfishopolis.com/?s=braid+hints

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each area in Braid introduces a special mechanism. The first level of each area, The Pit, allows you to experiment with the mechanism, so I would advice you to play around a bit first. That said, the special mechanism for the third region is:

> Objects that have a green glow around them are not affected by your time reversal ability

Therefore, the solution to the problem is to:

> Go down, kill the Goomba and get the key - note its green glow - and reverse time so that you get back to where you started. They key will remain in your hands, and you can then use it to open the door.

Here's a [YouTube video walkthough](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KCQulbe0CgA) if you need any more help.

Comment: Beautiful. I figured it out a few minutes after I asked this question just from playing around (mashing buttons). But thank you for this great answer!